# Solution to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when restoring RecyclerView state with ArrayList of custom objects and Gson

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, gson, sharedpreferences

I have a `RecyclerView` in which the views/data in the `ViewHolder`s (image, title, description) are retrieved with the getter methods of a custom object `Challenge`.

I also have an ArrayList of type `Challenge` (`ArrayList<Challenge> mChallenges`) where I add all the challenges and I later pass this ArrayList as a parameter of my RecyclerView.Adapter subclass when I initialize it.

The `ViewHolder`s of my `RecyclerView` also have a checkbox so users can select the challenges they want, and these chosen challenges are saved on a different `ArrayList<Challenge>` named `currentSelectedChallenges`. This is how they get added.

```
@Override
    public void onChallengeChecked(int position) {   // method of interface

    if (!currentSelectedChallenges.contains(mChallenges.get(position))){        
         currentSelectedChallenges.add(mChallenges.get(position));
    }
}
```

When the user leaves the fragment where the RecyclerView is contained, either with the back button or closing the app, I save the selected challenges `ArrayList<Challenge> currentSelectedChallenges` with a SharedPreferences using Gson like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Challenge>>(){}.getType();

    String json = gson.toJson(currentSelectedChallenges, type);

    editor.putString("selected challenges", json);

    editor.apply();
}
```

And I restore currentSelectedChallenges on the onRestore method of the fragment in the following way:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("selected challenges", null);

    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Challenge>>() {
    }.getType();

    currentSelectedChallenges = gson.fromJson(json, type);


    if (currentSelectedChallenges == null) {

        currentSelectedChallenges = new ArrayList<>();

    } else
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < currentSelectedChallenges.size(); i++) {

            int index = mChallenges.indexOf(currentSelectedChallenges.get(i));

            mChallenges.get(index).setChecked(true);

        }

        mChallengesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}
```

When I try to restore the checked state of the CheckBox in the ViewHolder I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` because `currentSelectedChallenges.get(i)` is not found inside `mChallenges`, so it returns -1. I have logged the challenges and the objects have different ids even though I can use the setter methods and will retrieve the same data.

I tried to trick Android and used this:

```
    for (int i=0; i < currentSelectedChallenges.size(); i++) {         

                    for (Challenge challenge : mChallenges) {                                           


                        if (challenge.getName().equals(currentSelectedChallenges.get(i).getName())){        

                            challenge.setChecked(true);     
                        }
                    }
mChallengesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And it does tick in the UI the challenges that were checked by the user but then when I click again on the CheckBox it doesn't detect my click, so I know this is not the proper solution.

Could anyone explain how should I tackle this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
mChallenges.indexOf(currentSelectedChallenges.get(i))
```

returns -1 because it compares reference instead of your interested data.
you should override `equals` and `hashCode` of `Challenge` class:

```
class Challenge{

// your current code

   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Challenge)) {
            return false;
        }

        Challenge challenge = (Challenge) o;

        return challenge.name.equals(name) /*&& compare other values for equality*/;
        // also check for null name if it is necessary 
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        //result = 31 * result + age; // other property
        //result = 31 * result + passport.hashCode();// other property
        return result;
    }

}
```